# Int and Float pointer. Can someone explain the output

Tags: c, pointers, floating-point

```
    int x; float *p;
     p = (float*)&x;
    *p = 2.35;
    printf("x:%f\n",x); //0.0000
    printf("x:%d\n",x); //1075209830
    printf("p:%f\n",*p); //2.350000
```

Is this something which comes under c undefined behaviour?

Comment: Yes it's UB. What output did you expect ?

Comment: Yes for two reasons: 1) You break the strict-aliasing rule 2) You use the wrong format specifier `%f` for an `int`.

Comment: i assume only the first printf needs explanation, but it entirely depends on how the arguments are passed to the function, which depends on the compiler mode and version. might be worth noting that vs2015 even produces a warning that an mistyped argument was used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have `&x` which holds a an address pointing to `x`, and a `p` likewise.
Then you change the value of `p`, ie. change that it points to `x` just that now when dereferencing `p` the bytes are intepreted as float. As (possibly) `sizeof(int) != sizeof(float)` even some Bytes are evaluated that weren't before or the other way around.
So you are accessing memory the C standard has no definitions for, ie. UB.

Furthermore you assign `*p` a new float value thus even writing to this space that'd used to be an `int`.
It's no wonder that when evaluating the first `printf()` the compiler is confused -- it's UB anyway.
The second statement atleast gives him non-contradictory instructions: Print an `int` from an `int` (and not try to interpret an `int` as `float`).
The third one got you lucky, since as I mentioned before, the `float` could possibly not fit into the `int` and thus the values being overriden at any time or even causing a SEGFAULT.